# Question with more upvotes is marked as duplicate... shouldn't the duplicate be the one with less upvotes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are two questions that ask the same thing and have the same answer: [here with 800+ upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/c-appending-a-vector-to-a-vector) and [here with 399 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stl-vectors) (upvotes are counting the question and the first answer and are counted as of 2015-06-09).

**The thing that strikes me as odd is that the one with more upvotes is the one that is marked as a duplicate. Shouldn't the one with less votes be marked as duplicate?**

I've run across this a number of times. But this time it is a question with lots of votes AND there are multiple people who have marked it as duplicate (not just one). If there is multiple people marking it as duplicate, I figured perhaps there is a good explanation.

Comment: Question age also plays a factor and the the question that got marked as a duplicate is a lot newer then the other question.

Comment: another motivation for making the one with more votes be the non-duplicate: I was going through and marking questions as duplicates and the "suggested questions" are sorted by upvotes... the [question that had 399 votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stl-vectors) had soo few votes that it didn't even show up in the list of "suggested questions" because the list limits it to like 10. I had to manually copy/paste the [url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stl-vectors).

Comment: Also remember that a question/answer with more upvotes does not mean it is of higher quality, just that it got more attention at the right time.

Comment: The premise of stackoverflow as I understand it, is that "quality" is quantified with "number of votes". Given said premise, the question/answer with more upvotes has been judged as higher quality ... by a factor of 2 to 1 or more than **four hundred** people thought that the one question/answer was better.

Comment: Then you better break from that premise now. There are a gazillion things with tons of votes that are of questionable quality.

Comment: I would disagree with your suggestion that upvotes are somehow a quantitative measure of value: do you truly believe that `a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());` (at ~540 votes) is truly *twice as good* of an answer as `vector1.insert( vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end() );` (at ~220)?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith _as I understand it [...] "quality" is quantified with "number of votes"._ - Voting should be used to indicate quality, but assuming that "more votes == better quality" is completely wrong. First of all, the top answers to both questions are exactly identical, thus one cannot be better than the other. Second, your assumption would only hold if both posts had the same exposure, but the higher voted question has close to 1.5 times the views. And that doesn't even begin to take into account that voting is subjective and the voters might not be qualified to judge answer quality...

Comment: "quality" is ultimately more of a subjective thing as Joe, Mystical, apsillers have all pointed out. I agree quality is subjective and I am not debating that. ||| I am however stating that stackoverflow (and the network) does try to quantify quality with upvotes.

Comment: "the voters might not be qualified to judge answer quality" ah. this may be part of the answer to my question.

Answer (score 5):

It just doesn't matter, the Q+A is identical.  They got this many votes only thanks to Google juice, it used to rank SO hits quite high.  The short question simply got less juice because it has fewer keywords so fewer opportunities to match the search query.

There is otherwise no good reason to favor one over the other from a technical point of view, they truly are identical.  One of them should have been closed a long time ago, it unfortunately does take an SO user with enough rep to truly care.  The intersection of users with enough rep with users that care about trivial Q+A like this is a very small one.

Answer (score 0):

@HansPassant said that it doesn't matter but I disagree as there are more aspects that the technical.

If one of the questions is well written and the other not I think is better for the community to maintain the best as it will be recognized by people more easily.

And as comments in the question, get in mind that more up votes don't imply better quality.